# Special configurations on a circle from a homological algebra problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, integer-sequences

> Here is the short version of the combinatorial problem:
>
> Given a positive integer $n \geq 2$. Draw a circle with $2n$ points indexed by the numbers from $\mathbb{Z}/ 2n \mathbb{Z}$. We colour the points black and white and assume that there is at least one black point. Since the problem is invariant under rotation of the circle we can assume that the point 0 is black. Let $x_0=0< x_1 < x_2 < ... <x_r$ be the black points (corresponding to numbers in $\mathbb{Z}/ 2n \mathbb{Z}$) and assume always that there are no neighboring black points, meaning that $x_i \neq x_j \pm 1$ for all $i,j$.
>
> Define the Gorenstein dimension $g$ of such a configuration as the maximal distance between two black points such that only white points are between them.
>
> Call such a configuration interesting in case the following is true: There exist numbers $p,q$ with $p+q \frac{(-1)^{x_j+i+1}+1}{2}-[\frac{x_j+i+1}{2}] \neq 0$ mod $n$ for all $i=1,2,...,g-1$ and all $j$. Here [ ] denotes the floor function.
>
> **Main problem**: Enumerate the interesting configurations (up to rotation or not).

**More information:**

I translated a representation theoretic/homological problem into elementary combinatorics/number theory problem. I expected an easy solution but I can not really see what is behind that. So I pose the elementary problem here. (See the end of the post for the representation theoretic/homological background.)

**Elementary formulation:**

Given a positive integer $n \geq 2$. Draw a circle with $2n$ points indexed by the numbers from $\mathbb{Z}/ 2n \mathbb{Z}$. We colour the points black and white and assume that there is at least one black point. Since the problem is invariant under rotation of the circle we can assume that the point 0 is black. Let $x_0=0< x_1 < x_2 < ... <x_r$ be the black points (corresponding to numbers in $\mathbb{Z}/ 2n \mathbb{Z}$) and assume always that there are no neighboring black points, meaning that $x_i \neq x_j \pm 1$ for all $i,j$. We can write such configurations uniquely by indicating what $n$ is and which points are black.

For example: $n=4$ and the configuration is $[0,3,6]$, meaning that it is a circle with 8 points such that the points 0,3 and 6 are black and the others are white.

Define the Gorenstein dimension $g$ of such a configuration as the maximal distance between two black points such that only white points are between them. In the example $[0,3,6]$, the Gorenstein dimension is equal to 3.
Call such a configuration interesting in case the following is true: There exist numbers $p,q$ with $p+q \frac{(-1)^{x_j+i+1}+1}{2}-[\frac{x_j+i+1}{2}] \neq 0$ mod $n$ for all $i=1,2,...,g-1$ and all $j$. Here [ ] denotes the floor function. Here are the interesting configurations for $2 \leq n \leq 7$:

-n=2: none

-n=3:[0,3]

-n=4:[0,3,6]

-n=5:[0,5],[0,2,5,8],[0,3,5,8]

-n=6:[0,3,6,9],[0,2,4,7,10],[0,5,10],[0,2,4,7,9]

-n=7:[0,7], [0,5,10], [0,2,7,12], [0,5,7,12], [0,4,7,11], [0,3,6,9,12], [0,2,4,6,9,12], [0,2,4,7,9,12], [0,2,5,7,9,12].

I can not really see a pattern but maybe it is better to look (and count) at those configurations not up to rotation?

So the main question is as follows:

> Is there a nice characterisation of interesting configurations? What is their number up to (or not up to) rotation? Is there a closed formula?

I can for example prove that if all $x_i$ are even, the configuration is never interesting.

**Representation theoretic /homological background:**

This decides whether a representation-finite gendo-symmetric biserial algebra has finitistic dominant dimension equal to the Gorenstein dimension or equal to the Gorenstein dimension +1 (there can be only those two possibilities). See the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05965 for such algebras, which generalise the classical Brauer tree algebras.

A configuration is interesting iff the corresponding algebra has finitistic dominant dimension equal to the Gorenstein dimension +1. (Of course there might be a more clever way than translating the problem into combinatorics/number theory.)

edit: Here is the example of $n=2$ and configuration [0,2]: Then $x_0=0$ and $x_1=2$ and $g=2$. So there are two conditions: ($i=g-1=1$) $p+q-1 \neq 0 \mod 2$ and $p+q-2 \neq 0 \mod 2$. Clearly no $(p,q)$ exists satisfying both conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. There was a mistake. It has to be $\neq 0$ mod $n$ instead of $\neq 0 mod 2n$. I'll add [0,2] as an example.

Comment: Then I get something different for n=6 (quantity is the same, it's 4, but tuples are different). First, [0,5,10] and [0,2,7] are cyclic shifts of each other: [0,2,7]+10=[10,0,5] ($\mod12$ ). On the other hand, interesting must be also [0,2,4,7,9] (which up to cyclic shifts is the same as [0,2,5,7,9], [0,2,5,7,10], [0,3,5,7,10], or [0,3,5,8,10]). For n=7 I get the same result. The numbers up to 12 I get are 0,0,1,1,3,4,9,15,38,80,197,461, does this match with your calculations?

Comment: Thanks again, I think you are right with n=6 altough I cannot check it on this computer at the moment. I also got the same sequence until 38. I calculated two more steps but forgot it. Can check it again when Im in my office.

Comment: Maybe it could be a good idea to count certain subconfigurations. Like the number of interesting configurations on n points having exactly (or at most) 2 (or 3 or 4 ,...) black points.

Comment: had no luck finding things in http://oeis.org/ yet, so maybe the configurations could be really some sort of random?

Comment: or count the uninteresting configurations instead. Ill add some more sequences if I can in some days (need to be at my office computer for that). If anyone finds something interesting (for example appearing in http://oeis.org/ ) like that he can also post it as an answer.

Comment: There are some patterns if counting configurations with fixed numbers of black points, but the whole thing seems to be quite complicated.$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
1\\0&1\\1&0&2\\0&1&1&2\\1&1&3&1&3\\0&1&4&4&3&3\\1&1&6&11&10&5&4\\0&2&6&18&26&14&10&4\\1&1&11&23&59&56&27&14&5\\0&2&10&36&87&144&113&42&22&5\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you post more like that? I found some sequences in that and want to check if it continues the right way. If its too large you can also post it as an answer.

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C2&sort=&language=english&go=Search thats what i get when I count the interesting configurations with at most 3 black points till n=14.

Comment: I have to optimize my code first, the way it is now it will certainly choke beyond 14. A couple of observations: if you take an interesting configuration for $n$ and insert after any black point one white and one black point, you obtain an interesting configuration for $n+1$. Thus certain amount of configurations can be accounted for from previous ones. This is not much, but...

Comment: http://oeis.org/A008610 could that be the second diagonal in your picture?

Comment: Hm, might well be - it has to do with necklaces :D The second observation I promised: if you take an interesting configuration with $g>2$ for $n$ and insert after a black point three white and one black point, you get an interesting configuration for $n+2$, but there is one exception: the configuration with consecutive distances between nearest black points 3,3,...,3,3,4 is not interesting, although the one with distances 3,3,...,3,3 is. There may be similar constructions, maybe ultimately generating everything from the configurations [0,2k-1] (for n=2k-1).

Comment: A correction to the above - not $g>2$ but the **minimal** distance between neighboring black points $>2$.

Comment: The minimal distance is by the way also a famous homological dimension when interpreting those configurations as algebras. Namely the dominant dimension.

Comment: might also have to do with partitions: http://oeis.org/A103221 is exactly the sequence with 3 black points starting at n=3 to n=14 (more my pc cant do at the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple characterization of interesting configurations:

**Lemma.** A configuration $x_0=0< x_1 < x_2 < ... <x_r$ of Gorenstein dimension $g$ is *interesting* if and only if there exist indices $i,j$ such that $x_i$ is even, $x_j$ is odd, and
$$x_{i+1} - x_i \equiv x_{j+1}-x_j \equiv g\pmod{2n},$$
where the indices are considered modulo $r+1$.

We can also specify particular values of $p,q$ that will do the job:
$$(p,q) = \begin{cases}
\big(-\frac{x_{j+1}}2, \frac{x_j - x_i - 1}2\big), & \text{if $g$ is odd};\\
\big(-\frac{x_{i+1}}2, \frac{x_i - x_j - 1}2\big), & \text{if $g$ is even}.
\end{cases}$$

---

Let's now enumerate the interesting configurations for given $n$ and $g$.

We find it convenient to employ the transfer-matrix method by viewing each configuration as a closed walk in the algebraically weighted digraph $G$ on two nodes: `Even` and `Odd` corresponding to the parities of black points. We will need to keep track of: the number of black points, their total span (which  should be $2n$ at the end), and of the number of steps of length $g$ taken from each of the nodes (each should be at least 1). These quantities will be accounted as the powers of indeterminates $x, y,z,t$.
Correspondingly, $G$ has the following arcs:

- `Even` to `Even` of weight
  $$y^2 + y^4 + \dots + y^{2\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor} + [g\text{ is even}]\cdot zy^g= y^2\frac{1-y^{2\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor}}{1-y^2} + [g\text{ is even}]\cdot zy^g;$$
- `Odd` to `Odd` of weight
  $$y^2 + y^4 + \dots + y^{2\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor} + [g\text{ is even}]\cdot ty^g= y^2\frac{1-y^{2\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor}}{1-y^2} + [g\text{ is even}]\cdot ty^g;$$
- `Even` to `Odd` of weight
  $$y^3 + y^5 + \dots + y^{2\lfloor g/2\rfloor-1} + [g\text{ is odd}]\cdot zy^g= y^3\frac{1-y^{2\lfloor (g-2)/2\rfloor}}{1-y^2} + [g\text{ is odd}]\cdot zy^g;$$
- `Odd` to `Even` of weight
  $$y^3 + y^5 + \dots + y^{2\lfloor g/2\rfloor-1} + [g\text{ is odd}]\cdot ty^g= y^3\frac{1-y^{2\lfloor (g-2)/2\rfloor}}{1-y^2} + [g\text{ is odd}]\cdot ty^g.$$

Consider matrix $M:=(I_2-xA)^{-1}$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Let $f_e(x,y,z,t):=M_{1,1}$ and $f_o(x,y,z,t):=M_{1,2}$, and further define
$$F_g(x,y) := f_e(x,y,1,1) - f_e(x,y,1,0) - f_e(x,y,0,1) + f_e(x,y,0,0) +
f_o(x,y,1,1) - f_o(x,y,0,0).$$
For example, for even $g$, we have
$$F_g(x,y) = \frac{{\left(2 \, x y^{2} - x y^{g + 2} - x y^{g} + 2 \, y^{2} - 2\right)} {\left(y^{g-2}-1\right)} x^{2} y^{g + 3}}{{\left(x^{2} y^{4} - x^{2} y^{g + 2} - 2 \, x y^{2} + x y^{g + 2} + x y^{g} - y^{2} + 1\right)} {\left(x y^{2} - x y^{g + 1} + y - 1\right)} {\left(x y^{2} - x y^{g} - y - 1\right)}}$$
and there is a similar expression in the case of odd $g$.

Then the number of interesting configurations with $k$ black points equals $[x^ky^{2n}]\ F_g(x,y)$, and without fixing $k$ (ie. summing over all $k$) it is $[y^{2n}]\ F_g(1,y)$. Up to rotation, the number of interesting configurations with $k$ black points equals
$$\frac1k \sum_{d\mid \gcd(2n,k)} \phi(d)\cdot [x^{k/d}y^{2n/d}]\  F_g(x,y),$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually the number up to rotation is much more interesting as it corresponds to the algebras up to isomorphism. I wonder whether there is a nice formula, but your calculations make it look like the end result might not be so nice.

Comment: @Mare: I have improved my answer, which now includes a formula for the number of interesting configurations up to rotation.